# css stack center div on top of two others

Tags: css, html

this should be fairly simple. I'm trying to center a div on top of two other divs, however I don't know how to make it stay there when the window is re-sized.

```
#middle{
    z-index:10;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:15px solid #232323;
    background: #232323;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    top:180px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

I just want the "middle" div centered in between the other two and in the middle of the page. Please have a look at the fiddle and let me know what I can do here.

http://jsfiddle.net/VwRkC/

I've been tinkering but I am not very experienced with css.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#middle{
    z-index:10;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:15px solid #232323;
    background: #232323;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    top:180px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -215px; /* This is half the total width (width + border + padding) */
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make `position:absolute;` work without adding a `position:relative;` to its parent div.

In your case, you need to add a `position:relative;` to the `wrapper` id.

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VwRkC/3/)**

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Only `position:absolute;` will make the div to take its position relative of your screen. By applying a `position:relative;` to the parent div of the absolutely position div, will make the absolute position div to take its positioning from the relative positioning of its parent div.

Comment: +1 thank you i did not know about the parent needing to be set to relative

Comment: Only `position:absolute;` will make the div to take position relative of your screen. By applying a `position:relative;` to the parent div of the absolutely position div, will make the absolute position div to take its positioning from the relative positioning of its parent div.